# Concavity of a function along a path

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function
and $g(x,y) =xy-f(x,y)$. I know that $g$ is concave
if and only if $(-f_{xx})(-f_{yy}) -(1-f_{xy}) ^{2}>0$ and $f_{xx}>0$.

Now suppose that I "travel" along the function $g$ on a path that satisfies 
$f_{x}=y$. Thus, along this path $f_{xy}=1$.

Is it correct that *along the path* the function $g$ is concave if and only if $
(-f_{xx}) (-f_{yy}) >0$ and $f_{xx}>0$ ? An explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*along the path* the function $g$ is concave"?

Comment: I mean the following. Suppose that $\left( x_{1},y_{1}\right) ,\left(
x_{2},y_{2}\right) $ and $\left( x_{3},y_{3}\right) $ satisfy $f_{x}\left(
x_{1},y_{1}\right) =y_{1}$, $f_{x}\left( x_{2},y_{2}\right) =y_{2}$,$
f_{x}\left( x_{3},y_{3}\right) =y_{3}$ and $x_{2}=\lambda x_{1}+\left(
1-\lambda \right) x_{3}$ for some $\lambda \in \left( 0,1\right) $. Then $
f\left( x_{2},y_{2}\right) >\lambda f\left( x_{1},y_{1}\right) +\left(
1-\lambda \right) f\left( x_{3},y_{3}\right) $. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Of course, your "if and only if" statement is incorrect. E.g., let 
$$f(x,y):=x^2/2+y^2/4.$$
Then your conditions $(-f_{xx})(-f_{yy})>0$ and $f_{xx}>0$ obviously hold. Further, here 
$f_x(x,y)=y$ means $y=x$, and hence the concavity of $g$ *along the path* means that $g(x,x)$ is concave in $x$. However, $g(x,x)=x^2/4$ is strictly convex, and thus not concave, in $x$.

---

As for your reasoning, if you try to formalize it, avoiding terms such as "along the path" and "travel", perhaps you will see where you made mistakes. Hints: (i) $f_x(x,y(x))=y(x)$ does not imply $f_{xy}(x,y(x))=1$ (you are confusing independent and dependent variables here) and (ii) the concavity of $g(x,y)$ in $(x,y)$ means that the restriction of $g$ to every straight line is concave, and this concavity does not in general imply any kind of concavity over curved lines.